# ActionScript3.0 - How to get color (uint) of pixel at coordinates? (Stage3D, Flare3D)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, colors, pixel, stage3d

Question is in the title:

[ActionScript3.0] How to get color (uint) of pixel at coordinates? (Stage3D, Flare3D)

I am using Flare3D library to render 3D scene on an iPad2. I need to get color values at 768 different coordinates every time screen is redrawn. Previously, on simple stage (2D), I could just  draw it on 1x1 bitmaps translated to specified coordinates, now it does not work on stage3D. Plus, I am a bit worried weather it will kill the performance since I really need to do it as often as possible - actually every time screen is drawn.
It would be really nice if that currently displayed screen was like a bitmap somewhere, so I could access it like simple array...but yeah, I am not holding my breath:)

Comment: It is possible to render scene to a bitmap but the process is painfully slow. Can you explain why you need to do this?

Comment: I actually need to get this information as a dataset, array of values, to pass on. For testing purposes I would like to draw corresponding value colored circles at these coordinates, but in the end, I just need the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Stage3D renders to back-buffer and one can't directly access it, you also need to render to BitmapData using Context3D.drawToBitmapData() method. Rendering to a bitmap is very slow, especially if the viewport is large. As you only need to access those 768 pixels, you could use Context3D.setScissorRectangle to render scene 768 times with the size of scissor rectangle set to 1x1 along with needed coordinates. I haven't tested that myself so I don't know if rendering scene 700 times won`t be slower than rendering it once, but you may want to try that. :)

Comment: Upvoted and I'll add my support on this: your only option is to render to bitmapData. To make it quick, reduce your viewport to 1x1 as Varnius mentioned. This is actually not terribly slow, and is used quite a bit as a way of implementing "picking". The guys at away3d wrote an excellent article on the subject that you might find valuable - http://away3d.com/tutorials/Introduction_to_Mouse_Picking  Jackson Dunstan also did some pretty in-depth analysis of the performance http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1446

Comment: Thanks for the idea! It did work, but even 10 points becomes a stutter. For single mouse point it work remarkably well, add more tests and you get slowed down significantly.